# TypeError when try to load information form website

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

I have a problem with getting information from a website to my python program. Thats what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc as odbc
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely
import shapefile
import sys
import datetime 

server = '....'
database = '<database>'
username = '<username >'
password = '<password>'   
driver={'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'}



sql_conn = odbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=....;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
query = "select * from view;"
df = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)
df.head()
```

Error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "set") to str
```

Does anybody know what I did wrong? I jusst want to collect the information and save it for further processing. I googled but could not find a mistake...

Comment: Are you using pyodbc? ... pypyodbc? ... TurbODBC? ... something else?

Comment: I'm using pyodbc

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`driver={'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'}` driver is a python [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

change to `driver='ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'`

See [https://snakify.org/en/lessons/sets/#:~:text=Set%20in%20Python%20is%20a,union%2C%20intersection%2C%20difference](https://snakify.org/en/lessons/sets/#:%7E:text=Set%20in%20Python%20is%20a,union%2C%20intersection%2C%20difference)).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add *str* type to *set* type

```
'DRIVER='+driver+'
```

as you defined driver as string in curly braces, which means: set with given string as sole element. Probably you meant to define it as string, so delete braces; otherwise you, you can get (random) element from set using

```
next(iter(driver))
```